# Rest API + OAuth2 - trusted mobile application

Tags: spring-boot, oauth

I'm an Android newcomer - just starting learning the system by writing my first mobile application for personal use.

I faced an issue with the Rest API developed by Spring and secured by OAuth. What OAuth flow should be used to authenticate the client and fetch the access token to the API?

What I'm trying to achieve is the user experience offered by Google or Facebook mobile apps - just login into the app without any redirects, approval screens.

I'm looking for a solution for a few days - no luck - that's why I've decided to ask a question.